# WebCamTexture brings black screen only

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
 objWebCam = new WebCamTexture();
        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = objWebCam;
        //mat.mainTexture = objWebCam;
        objWebCam.Play();
```

simplist code it detected the webcam but not showing the image instead black screen

Comment: Did you turn the light in the room? Sorry stupid joke :D

Comment: it's incredibly hard to use the web cam texture, Mohammad.  today everyone just uses NatCam (see asset store).  you do have to pay a few $ but it saves literally 2 to 3 man months of time.  Realistically, Unity ***does not offer*** web cam support. You can only say "it's broken and doesn't work at all".  Unity should just remove it until they get around to programming web cam stuff.

Comment: it is a costly solution i am unable to do this webCamTexture worked now but today i am getting this "Could not connect pins - RenderStream()".

Comment: it seems that your comments are true